# ¿Como añado un valor booleano a un elemento concreto de un array objeto?

Tags: javascript

Quiero añadir un valor booleano a cada uno de estos elementos dentro de este array objeto. No puedo declarar variable dentro y poniendo: i=true; o i=true,    no me lo acepta, así que supongo que debe tener otra sintaxis o no se podrá hacer.
¿Alguien me lo puede explicar por favor?

Este es el array objeto al que quiero añadir valores booleanos:

```
var book = [{
        title: "The Giver 1",
        autor: "Manueh",
        stars: 4,

    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 2",
        autor: "Jesu",
        stars: 3
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 3",
        autor: "KIKO",
        stars: 1
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 4",
        autor: "jaimie",
        stars: 5
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 5",
        autor: "jijon",
        stars: 4
}];
```

Comment: Al igual que el resto de valores, puedes poner el nombre del atributo y el valor, usando dos puntos (`:`) en lugar del `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un forma sencilla es crear el elemento directamente especificando la posición:

```
book[0].i = true;
```

En donde "0" es la posición del elemento al que se desea agregar la propiedad. Con un "**FOR**" podría agregar la propiedad a todos los elementos.

Comment: Sip, ha funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código que debes usar para añadirlo:

```
for(var i=0; i < book.length; i++){
    book[i].nuevobooleano = true;
}
```

Comment: Se refiere a añadir un atributo booleano a cada objeto del array. La respuesta es la que le comenta @Pablo-lozano en el comentario

Comment: Es posible la verdad pense que lo quería dinámico en todo caso lo dejo para que tenga las 2 formas de hacerlo. @Kiko_L

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya está respondida, te dejo una explicación para que entiendas un poco mejor la dinámica de tu `array` de objetos.

Existen varias formas de crear objetos en `javascript` y definir sus propiedades. Estas son las dos más comunes:

```js
// Con {} creas un objeto vacío y luego puedes añadir las propiedades que quieras con objeto.propiedad = valor

var book = {};
book.title = "Todos los buenos soldados";
book.author = "David Finkel";
book.stars = 5;
book.read = true;

console.log(book);

//Con {} pero inicializando los valores (atento porque se utilizan los dos puntos)
var book = {
  title: "Todos los buenos soldados",
  author: "David Finkel",
  stars: 5,
  read: true
 }

console.log(book);

//Añado una nueva propiedad. Como ves, a tu objeto book se le ha añadido la propiedad numberOfReads
book.numberOfReads = 2;
console.log(book);

//Con new Object(). Equivalente a {}
var book = new Object();
book.title = "Todos los buenos soldados";
book.author = "David Finkel";
book.stars = 5;
book.read = true;

console.log(book);
```

En tu ejemplo tendríamos una propiedad `read` que está inicializada al principio y luego creo otra propiedad `numberOfReads` en tiempo de ejecución:

```
var LibrosXestante= 3;

var book = [{
    title: "La comedia humana",
    stars: 4,
    author: "Honoré de Balzac",
    read: true
},
{
    title: "Guerra y paz",
    stars: 4,
    author: "Tolstoi",
    read: false
},
{
    title: "Vida y destino",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Vasili Grossman",
    read: true
},
{
    title: "Crimen y castigo",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Fiódor Dostoievski",
    read: true
},
{
    title: "The sunset limited",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Cormac McCarthy",
    read: false
}];

var y = 140;
// Pintar estantes
for (var i = 0; i < ceil(book.length/LibrosXestante); i++) {
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, y, width, 10);
    y = y + 150;
}
//Variable para contar los libros impresos
var booksPrinted = 0;

//Función para pintar libro
var pintarLibro = function(xBook,yBook,i) {
    fill(214, 255, 219);
    rect(10 + xBook, yBook, 90, 115); 
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(book[i].title, 15 + xBook, yBook+5, 80, 100);
    textSize(10);
    text(book[i].author, 15 + xBook, yBook+50, 60, 100);
    //Si el libro está leído ponemos el texto "Leído"
    if(book[i].read){
        textSize(8);
        text("Leido ", 15 + xBook, yBook+80, 60, 100);
        //Creamos un nuevo atributo en nuestro objeto con un valor, por ejemplo,          //(i+1) * 2. Este nuevo atributo representa el número de lecturas.
        book[i].numberOfReads = (i+1) * 1;
        text(book[i].numberOfReads, 37 + xBook, yBook+80, 60, 100);
        if(((i+1) * 1) === 1){
            text(" vez", 40 + xBook, yBook+80, 60, 100);
        }
        else{
            text(" veces", 40 + xBook, yBook+80, 60, 100);
        }
    }
    textSize(12);

    //Si no hemos llegado al máximo de libros por estante sumamos uno
    if(booksPrinted<LibrosXestante){
        booksPrinted++;
    }
};

//Función para pintar las estrellas
var pintarEstrellas = function(i,yStars,xStars){
    for (var j = 0; j < book[i].stars; j++) {
        image(getImage("cute/Star"), (xStars + j * 15), yStars, 20, 30);
    }
};

var yBook = 25;
var xBook = 0;
var yStars = 110;
var xStars = 15;

// draw books
for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
    //Si hemos llegado al máximo de libros impresos saltamos de estante 
    //y reinicializamos las variables
    if(booksPrinted>=LibrosXestante){
        yBook = yBook + 150;
        xBook = 0;
        yStars = yStars + 150;
        xStars = 15;
        //Inicializamos de nuevo los libros impresos
        booksPrinted = 0;
    }
    pintarLibro(xBook,yBook,i);
    pintarEstrellas(i,yStars,xStars);
    xStars = xStars + 100;
    xBook = xBook + 100;
}
```

Si puedes échale un vistazo a [este](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) recurso porque explica muy bien todo lo relacionado con objetos.

Comment: Vale creo que me ha servido bastante para comprender como funciona, muchas gracias por el aporte!!!